# How to count number of nights booked per month with check-in and check-out dates having different months in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset like the below dataset. I want to find the number of nights each id was occupied per month. For some rows, the check-in and checkout dates are in different months. I want to know how to write a query to have the occupancy per month. For example, for id=1, check-in: 2020-01-26 and checkout date: 2020-03-02. How can I have a table that shows January occupancy: 6, Feb occupancy: 29, and March occupancy: 1

| id | check-in | checkout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-26 | 2020-03-02 |
| 2 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-20 |
| 3 | 2020-06-29 | 2020-07-03 |

The outcome should be like this:

| id | Month | Occupancy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 06 |
| 1 | Feb | 29 |
| 1 | Mar | 01 |
| 2 | Apr | 19 |
| 3 | Jun | 02 |
| 3 | Jul | 02 |

Comment: Show what you've tried so far....

Answer (score 1):

first, you need a `numbers table` or `tally table` , after you can easily to it using this query :

```
select c.id,
    case when m.id <> 0 
        then adddate(last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id -1 month)),interval 1 day)
        else checkin_date 
    end as Checkin_date,
    case when last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id month)) > checkout_date 
        then checkout_date 
        else last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id month)) 
    end checout_date,
    datediff(case when last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id month)) > checkout_date 
                then checkout_date 
                else last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id month)) end,
             case when m.id <> 0 
                then last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id -1 month))
                else adddate(checkin_date, interval -1 day) end
            ) daysdiff
from checkins c
join numbers m on m.id <= period_diff(date_format(checkout_date, "%Y%m"),date_format(checkin_date, "%Y%m"))
order by  c.id, checkin_date
```

this is works for any gap (for more than 1 year)

you can use`date_format` to show month :

```
select
     date_format(case when m.id <> 0 
        then adddate(last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id -1 month)),interval 1 day)
        else checkin_date 
    end, '%Y %M') as month_year
    ,sum(datediff(case when last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id month)) > checkout_date 
                then checkout_date 
                else last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id month)) end,
             case when m.id <> 0 
                then last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id -1 month))
                else adddate(checkin_date, interval -1 day) end
            )) Occupancy
from checkins c
join numbers m on m.id <= period_diff(date_format(checkout_date, "%Y%m"),date_format(checkin_date, "%Y%m"))
group by date_format(case when m.id <> 0 
        then adddate(last_day(adddate(checkin_date, interval m.id -1 month)),interval 1 day)
        else checkin_date 
    end, '%Y %M') 
order by month_year
```

```
 month_year    | Occupancy
 :------------ | --------:
 2020 April    |        20
 2020 February |        29
 2020 January  |         6
 2020 July     |         3
 2020 June     |         2
 2020 March    |         2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a467562740dad99d8728c6a6774c8b6d)*

Comment: I was not aware of Fiddle (Online DB interface). **New Learning :)** 
@eshirvana Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my question to show what outcome I want to reach

Comment: @Rahom see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want month-wise aggregated result of occupied inventory.

You can try below simple aggregate query as based on 'Group by' clause then add more criteria logic based on your need if required

```
select monthname(check_in) as 'Month', sum(dayofyear(check_out) - dayofyear(check_in)) as 'Occupied_days'
from inventory 
where year(check_in)=year(check_out) 
group by 1;
```

**Note:** Above query will work only for dataset where check_in & check_out happened within same year.

Check sample query output [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd6206cc4b851d291dcf7cd4aefad084) in Fiddle

Comment: This Query is compatible with mysql for other database, you can try similar db functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my question to show what outcome I want to reach